# BigInteger in Pascal

Tags: biginteger, freepascal

Is there BigInteger type exists in Free Pascal?
In Java and C# exists the type BigInteger and BigDecimal.
How can I write the same code I have written in Java below in Pascal:

```
package bigint;
import java.math.BigInteger;
/** 
 * @author Istvan
 */
public class bigint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger a = new BigInteger("12345678913546876542545054683656469434");
        BigInteger b = new BigInteger("983435472457463464685743648468650354684046846841");

        BigInteger c = a.multiply(b);
        System.out.println("c="+c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find a few different solutions in **[this Lazarus forum thread](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=9375.0)** and **[here](http://sergworks.wordpress.com/2013/08/03/numerics-for-delphi-fpc/)**.

Comment: @arva Which one of it do You recomment?

Comment: I haven't used any since I didn't have a need for them yet.